# install a package with pip (or pip3) in python3

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

ubuntu 14.04

I'm new to python and I'm having trouble installing packages. I've looked at similar questions to mine, but it's hard to tell if it's relevant and up to date.

I'm not sure what I need to do to get this to work.

```
pip --version
The program 'pip' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: 
sudo apt-get install python-pip


pip3 --version
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.4)
```

and I've got several versions of python, the latest;

```
python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
```

When I try install a package

```
pip3 install copy
Downloading/unpacking copy
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement copy
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for copy
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ben/.pip/pip.log
```

I saw in similar stackoverflow questions, that people went to the log and posted that as well.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/bin/pip3 run on Thu Aug 18 20:25:27 2016
Downloading/unpacking copy
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/copy/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/copy/: 404 Client             Error: Not Found
Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/copy/ when looking for    download links for copy
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/
URLs to search for versions for copy:
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/copy/
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/copy/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/copy/: 404 Client  Error: Not Found
Will skip URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/copy/ when looking for  download links for copy
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement copy
Cleaning up...
Removing temporary dir /tmp/pip_build_ben...
No distributions at all found for copy
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in  main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line  278, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle,   bundle=self.bundle)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in  prepare_files
url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 277, in  find_requirement
raise DistributionNotFound('No distributions at all found for %s' % req)
pip.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No distributions at all found for   copy
```

Other answers say something like 
"You need to fetch pypi over HTTPS, not HTTP." but I don't really understand that or what I need to do to fix that.

So my question is; what do I need to do to be able to install the python3 version of a package? Do I need to install pip, or is it better to use pip3?

Comment: [I can't find a package `copy` on PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/copy/). Are you certain that this is the package you want to install?

Comment: Like @NilsWerner said, your problem is the package you are trying to install doesn't exist. This makes the rest of the question moot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several versions of python, make sure to navigate in the directory of the python version you want to use, go to 'Scripts' folder and run the pip command there. Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this package is not available on PyPi. What are you trying to install?
Your pip version is quite old - pip 1.5.4. [current version is 8.1.2](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/).

You can also use `pip install -v` to get more information while installing.